# D3 Tile Map Offline

Tags: d3.js, openstreetmap, offline

What's the best way to allow D3 map tiles to work without internet connection. For example, how can I change [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797) so that it still loads offline? Is there a way to download the tiles ahead of time such that the API calls can work in a similar way?

Comment: Install .NodeJS, install the modules and run a local web server.